# QFile. Device not open

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I have problem with `QFile`.

```
QFile file1("file1.dat");
QFile file2("file2.dat");

if(file2.exists())
{

}

if(!file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug() << "Ошибка открытия для чтения";
}

if(!file2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    qDebug() << "Ошибка открытия для записи";
}

QByteArray block = file1.readAll();
file2.write(block);
file1.close();
file2.close();
```

**ERROR:**

```
QIODevice::read (QFile, "file1.dat"): device not open
```

Comment: try to use ```fileN.isOpen() ``` check, for both files, to be sure they are opened. As a second step I will check their location.

Comment: Where I need to write fileN.isOpen()?   
Qt already says that file1 is not opened.    
Also I just wrote QFile file1("file1.dat");
I want to say that I didn't create file1.dat

Comment: In the code shown, if `file1.open(...)` fails you still go ahead and try to read from it with `file1.readAll()`.

Comment: What do you expect? The file can't be opened - likely it isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to open file1.dat in read-write mode:

```
if(!file1.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    qDebug() << "Ошибка открытия";
}
```

Because if you open it just for reading, it cannot be created if it doesnt exist, or create it manually at first.

and in case that file is not opened you are not doing anything, so just for being sure check if both files were opened at first:

```
if(file1.isOpen() && file2.isOpen()){
    QByteArray block = file1.readAll();
    file2.write(block);
    file1.close();
    file2.close();
}
```

Comment: Is it Workable?
QFile File("/Users/Sardorkun/Destkop/File.txt");

Comment: Also where I need to create file1.dat?

Comment: If It was created, where I can find file1.dat?

Comment: have a look on QT Documentation of QDir, methods like ```QDir::currentPath()``` or similar can be useful. And then just use ```qDebug()``` to print folder where file was created. But at first I will look to the folder, where executable is situated. (May vary depending on operating system)

Comment: Please can you help me with my other problem? Its about sdk platforms. I already ask this question.

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me. But it gave me a good clue: my file was misplaced and I was surprized when it was created empty in unexpected location. Eventually, I turned QIODevice::ReadOnly back when the path was fixed.